# Problems in upgrading pip packages

Tags: raspbian-wheezy, pip

I am having some troubles with `pip`on the Raspberry.
These are the information about the OS:

```
piName@raspberry ~ $ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 7 (wheezy)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="7"
VERSION="7 (wheezy)"
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
ANSI_COLOR="1;31"
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"

piName@raspberry ~ $ uname -a                                                   
Linux piname 4.1.19+ #858 Tue Mar 15 15:52:03 GMT 2016 armv6l GNU/Linux
```

My Python version associated with pip is 2.7.3, although I have also Python3 installed.

First when I list the outdated pip packages I get the following warning (sorry for the verbosity):

```
pip list --outdate
DEPRECATION: The default format will switch to columns in the future. 
You can use --format=(legacy|columns) (or define a format=(legacy|columns) 
in your pip.conf under the [list] section) to disable this warning.
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages
/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:318: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been 
made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not 
available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an 
incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. You can 
upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, 
see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest
/security.html#snimissingwarning.
      SNIMissingWarning
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages
/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:122: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object 
is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately 
and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer 
version of Python to solve this. For more information, see 
https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest
/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
      InsecurePlatformWarning
```

Some packages can be upgraded, some others cannot. For example `pip install --upgrade scipy` gives errors and one of this is the following

```
    Failed building wheel for scipy
  Running setup.py clean for scipy
  Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-pmGCTQ/scipy/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" clean --all:

  `setup.py clean` is not supported, use one of the following instead:

    - `git clean -xdf` (cleans all files)
    - `git clean -Xdf` (cleans all versioned files, doesn't touch
                        files that aren't checked into the git repo)

  Add `--force` to your command to use it anyway if you must (unsupported)`enter code here`
```

Note that wheel is installed.

Also I have errors trying to upgrade numpy.

Does anyone know how to solve these issues?

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but if you use an obsolete, unsupported OS there will be no updates. Recently Python wheels have been added for most common packages including `scipy` - if you use a current Raspbian `pip` will install these.

Comment: As specified in the question the packages scipy and others are already installed. Apart from this, are you suggesting I should install jessie instead of raspbian wheezy?

Comment: No - I do not recommend Jessie which is only fully supported until June. Use the current stable release `Stretch`

Comment: Ok  apart from the specific OS, you are suggesting to update my OS? Should I format my SD card to do that or there is a way an less invasive way?

Comment: You are welcome to continue to use `Wheezy` if it works - but don't expect any support. There is no official upgrade path from Wheezy to Jessie/Stretch, although there are those who claim to have upgraded. Buy a new card, they are cheap enough, and you will need at least 8GB, preferably 16.

Answer (score 3):

Three Suggestions

1. Use Virtualenv for development and custom applications, System python is for installed programs

   - System python is better suited for system utilities which are built against the packaged python and expect the versions to match the dependencies specified in `apt.
   - By upgrading anything using `pip` outside of `apt` you risk breaking the dependencies.
   - Avoid using pip to upgrade or install system wide packages, use apt instead
2. As a standard course I would try to update pip itself.

   - Create a virtualenv `virtualenv ~/myvenv && source ~/myvenv/bin/activate`
   - Execute `pip install --upgrade pip`
   - Install scipy from scratch `pip install scipy`
3. If you require Python3, you must do so explicitly

   - Install pip3 so it is available in virtualenv's `apt-get install python3-pip`
   - Create a virtualenv using python3 explicitly `virtualenv -P python3 ~/myvenv3`
   - Use `pip3` to install packaged (in a python3 virtualenv, sometimes `pip->pip3`)

---

It is generally not recommended to use pip to manage system wide python packages, because the system bundled python is used to run installed utilities and sysadmin programs that are installed from `apt` which will depend and are built against the version of python bundled with the OS.

You may have issues when for example, you install a program from apt which depends on a library/package also bundled in `apt` , but you have gone and updated that outside of `apt` using `pip`, it may break an installed program or cause your system to fail to function.

The typical use is to install pip and then use `virtualenv` to create sand-boxed environments for development and custom applications

Comment: Do you think uninstalling the packages and then installing with virtualenv might work?

Comment: Is it not a problem that my OS is wheezy (instead of Jessy) that might be outdated?

Comment: There is no need to "uninstall" packages  as virtualenv (by default) does not copy existing packages except `pip`.  In fact, using a legacy OS, which may be required for other reasons, is a great use case for virtualenv. It allows you to use the updated libraries without needing to upgrade the whole OS

Comment: Yeah maybe if I had used virtualenv from the start I would not have this problem now. But virtualenv cannot solve the conflicts (if my problem is related to package conflicts) that are already present.

Comment: That doesn't sound right, a clean virtualenv should have nothing in it.  However, A while back, virtualenv did install system packages, it is possible that wheezy packaged virtualenv still has this behavior. Try to do `virtualenv --no-site-packages ~/myvenv`

Comment: Wait maybe I was not clear in my comment or I am missing something. Until today i did not use virtualenv. Now if I create a virtualenv I can work cleanly and maybe this problem does not appear. However outside the virtualenv the problem persists and it seems a  serious one. The system uses the environment outside the newly created virtualenv (I guess) so the system keeps having the problem.

Comment: Yes, in this case it is prudent to reinstall any corrupted packages using `apt`